# Webpack 5 use html-loader to load svgs

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, webpack-5, webpack-html-loader

I recently upgraded to Webpack 5 and my html-loader no longer loads svg files and inlines them.

Here's my svg rule in webpack

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: [
    {
       loader: 'html-loader',
       options: {
           minimize: true,
       },
    },
  ],
},
```

No matter how I try to import it, it seems to just create a file and not give me a string of HTML.

```
import mySvg from "../path/to/my.svg"

let mySvg = require("../path/to/my.svg").default;

// output = "/build/path/my.svg"
// output I want = "<svg>...."
```

It used to not give me several build files instead it inlined them in my JS.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have listed some options at https://survivejs.com/webpack/loading/images/#loading-svgs . I wonder if one of those would fit your use case.

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen Thank you, the svg-inline loader worked!

Comment: Thanks, I moved that as an answer so you can mark the issue as resolved. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### webpack 5 and above

Use raw-loader, asset/source (inlines as svg), or asset/inline (inlines as base64) loader.

### webpack 4 and earlier

[svg-inline-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-inline-loader) can achieve the same (confirmed to work).

I have listed other options for loading SVGs at https://survivejs.com/webpack/loading/images/#loading-svgs.

Comment: it is no longer maintained. use `raw-loader` or `asset/inline` loader in webpack 5.

Comment: Please provide an example using the "asset/inline" feature of Webpack 5, how to reference a SVG image inside a HTML document like `<img src="./images/logo.svg" />` , which than is embedded as `<svg>` entirely (<img> is removed). It seems to be impossible without external plugins and packages. But from the Docs it sounds like it should be possible.

Comment: I have an example at https://survivejs.com/webpack/loading/images/#loading-svgs . It all depends on how you are loading that HTML and it's difficult to tell more without detail. It's better to open a separate question with more information.

Comment: I depends use 'asset/source' to inline svg as svg, but 'asset/inline' to inline it as a base64

Answer (score 1):

I use [posthtml](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml) and [posthtml-inline-svg](https://github.com/andrey-hohlov/posthtml-inline-svg) plugin.

```
const postHtml = require('posthtml');
const postHtmlInlineSvg = require('posthtml-inline-svg');

{
  test: /\.html$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
      esModule: false,
      preprocessor: async (content, loaderContext) => {
        try {
          return await postHtml(postHtmlInlineSvg({ cwd: loaderContext.context, tag: 'icon', attr: 'src' }),).process(content)).html;
        } catch (error) {
          loaderContext.emitError(error);
          return content;
        }
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/), the [HtmlWebpackInlineSVGPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-inline-svg-plugin) can be used to inline svgs.

Here are the relevant parts of the webpack config to achieve the same:

```js
{
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html/,
        loader: "html-loader",
      },
      // ...
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackInlineSVGPlugin({
      inlineAll: true,
    }),
    // ...
  ]
}
```